# Match exact word using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression to match an exact word.

For example:

There is a string `"draft guidance allerg Excellence"` and I want to search `allerg` then I have written `\ballerg\b`. It gives me exact match. But when I pass string as `"draft guidance 12=allerg Excellence"` then it also return true, but this is wrong.

Which regular expression do I need to match only exact words?

Answer (score 6):

The `\b` boundary would normally handle this situation, even in your case of `"draft guidance 12=allerg Excellence"`; however, you're saying that the `=` is part of the word (in normal English, this is not the case).

I'm assuming then that by "whole word", you mean a word that is surrounded by a space or normal sentence punctuation. In this case, a regex such as the following should work:

```
(?:^|[\s\.;\?\!,])allerg(?:$|[\s\.;\?\!,])
```

You can, obviously, add or remove characters as needed.

Regex Explained:

```
(?:                     # non-matching group
    ^                   # beginning of string
    | [\s\.;\?\!,]      # OR a space, period, and other misc. punctuation
)
allerg                  # string to match
(?:                     # non-matching group
    $                   # end of string
    | [\s\.;\?\!,]      # OR a space, period, and other misc. punctuation
)
```

Comment: This will miss allerg if it is the first or last thing in the string.

Comment: @walrii Good catch! Updated to allow `allerg` to be at the beginning or end of the string too.

Comment: :) much better.  I don't think the +s are needed.  But they also don't hurt.

Comment: @walrii I was contemplating taking them out (and now have); I doubt there will be multiples (other than whitespace, or an ellipsis), but no point in checking for them when they're not needed - Thanks =]

Comment: The regex doesn't work if the input is "allerg allerg". Its gives only one match found, but actually there are two.

Comment: This regex works "(?:allerg(?:$|[\s\.;\?\!,]))" for the above input as well

Answer (score -1):

If i understood the question correctly, you want to match a word "allerg" . A word is enclosed with whitespace characters and "=allerg" has the "=" character which you dont want to match.

To match the word "allerg" you can use the following regex:

```
\s+allerg\s+
```

Comment: This will not catch the word if it is the first of last word, or if it is delimited with puctuation like a comma.